# Alternative to time-consuming loops for over year accumulated (YTM – Year-to-month) measurements

Tags: sql, pandas

I have an issue that I have been trying to solve for a long while and I now turn to you. I have two databases `DB1` and `DB2` and several criteria for the data that I need to handle:

```
ExcludeDates=['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04','2019-04-19','2019-04-22','2019-05-01','2019-05-31','2019-06-07','2019-12-21','2019-12-22','2019-12-23','2019-12-24','2019-12-25','2019-12-26','2019-12-27','2019-12-28','2019-12-29','2019-12-30','2019-12-31']
Region = ['Region1','Region2', 'Region3', 'Region4', 'Region5', 'Region6']
months        = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Now, I want to do a number of calculations with features retrieved from `DB1` and `DB2` over every `Region` accumulated over month, that is `Jan`, `Jan-Feb`, `Jan-Mar`, … ,`Jan-Dec`

My original idea, that works but is extremely inefficient (in some cases it takes up to 10 hours to execute, was to loop through all subset of the year (above shown as `Jan`, `Jan-Feb`, `Jan-Mar`, … ,`Jan-Dec`) and Regions in a loop nested in another loop:

```
Measure_ytm = []

for RegionName in Region:
    for month in months:
        year           = 2019
        month          = month
        System  = 'System1'
        SystemV = 'System1V'

        Query1 = """
        select 
        a.feature1
        ,a.feature2
        ,a.feature3
        from DB1 as a
        inner join DateTable1 as  cd on a.Date = cd.Date
        inner join TimeTable as ct on A.Time = ct.Time
        
        where 1=1 
        and a.feature6 = @System
        and cd. Year = @year
        and (cd.MonthOfYear between 1 and @month)
        """
        new_query = query1.replace('@feature6', '\'' + System + '\'').replace('@year', 
        str(year)).replace('@month', str(month))

        with pymssql.connect(server=server, user=user, password=password, database='BD1') as conn:
            with conn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(new_query)        
                all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
                df1 = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)

        query2 = """
        select
        b.Year as [Year]
       ,b.mon as [Month]
       , a.TId as [SystemV] 
       ,a.Name as [RegionName]
       , v.Namn as [Description]
       , m.Namn as [Type]
        ,b.Value
        from DB2 as b
        inner join MTable as m on b.MId=m.Id
        inner join VTable as v on b.VId=v.Id
        inner join AMTable as  a on b.AMId=a.Id
        where 1=1
        and f.Year=@year
        and (f.Mon between 1 and @month)
        and b.TId=@SystemV
        """
        query2 = query2.replace('@SystemV', '\'' + SystemV + '\'').replace('@year', 
        str(year)).replace('@month', str(month))

        with pymssql.connect(server=server, user=user, password=password, database='DB2') as conn:
            with conn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(new_query) 
                all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
                df2 = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)


### Follows a list of operations on the retrived dataframe df1 and df2 which result

        x  = <an array containing the YTM accumulated value, each value in the aray belonging to one Region>
       Measure_ytm.append(x)
```

Now, as mentioned earlier, this works just fine but takes up two 10 hours if all months are taken into account (i.e. if all `Jan`, `Jan-Feb`, `Jan-Mar`, … ,`Jan-Dec`) are executed. First pass is only January for all regions, second is Jan and Feb for all regions and so on. In some cases, because I might even change Region to a longer list of Regions, my PC runs out of memory.
I have tried to do this in another way by changing

```
months        = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

to

```
months        = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6],…..,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

And replacing `(cd.MonthOfYear between 1 and @month)` by `(cd.MonthOfYear in List)` where List is the list at each pass (i.e. if the loop is at pass 5 it’ll be `[1,2,3,4,5]`, but it doesn’t solve the issue.
Now, as a note: If only 1 month is taken each time, many of the operations that need to be done in the pandas part of the code can be done in the SQL-query part. And for all regions and months, the entire code takes 20 seconds to run (there are approximately 25 million rows in `DB1`.

**My question is thus**: Is there a more efficient way to do this? My guess would be avoiding loops, but how? My experience is that loop, in cases like this should be avoided and This proves me right. And it is evident that the use of `(cd.MonthOfYear between 1 and @month)` is a the root of the problem.

Thankful for any help from a community of bright people!

Comment: It looks like each dataset is just a union of the data for each month e.g. Jan-Feb is the union of the data for Jan and Feb. If this is the case then why don't you just run the query once for the whole year, Jan-Dec, and include the month and region as columns in your select statement. You can then select the records you want from this dataset in your code i.e. put the loop in your code only in the processing of df1/df2 rather than around your SQL as well?

Comment: It did solve the my issue. Went from 10 hours to 2 minutes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added my comment as an answer - please tick if it helped you out. Thanks

It looks like each dataset is just a union of the data for each month e.g. Jan-Feb is the union of the data for Jan and Feb. If this is the case then why don't you just run the query once for the whole year, Jan-Dec, and include the month and region as columns in your select statement. You can then select the records you want from this dataset in your code i.e. put the loop in your code only in the processing of df1/df2 rather than around your SQL as well?